# When requesting URL, returnUrl is null in my Login Action instead of being equal to the URL I want to redirect to after user is authenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, form-authentication, returnurl

I've been searching through some examples here, but could not find what I needed, so I'm posting my question here:

I'm using Form authentication and MVC 4.5.

The problem is following:

I'm emailing the URL to the user and the user needs to click on URL and be able to get redirected to that URL after he was authenticated.

My Login Controller has a method Index that is invoked when user tries to log in:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        try
        {
            LoginModel lm = LoginModel.AuthenticateUser(model.UserName, model.Password);
            if (lm.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                ApplicationSession.SetUser(lm.User);
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);

                if (lm.User.ChangePassword)
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("ForceChangePassword", "ChangePassword"));
                }
                else
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl ?? Url.Action("Index", "Details"));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (lm.GroupPermissionMessage.Length > 0)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", lm.GroupPermissionMessage);
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", lm.SaveResult.ErrorDescription);
                }

                return View();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", error.Message);
            return View();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The login form has the following definition:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "LoginForm", returnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }))
```

This is my logic that generates URL for the email:

```
 var queryString = @Url.Action("Index", "Details", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { id = model.Ticket.TicketId }), "http", Request.Url.Host);
                    var ticketUrl = "<a href='"
                                    + @Url.Action("Index", "Detail", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { id = model.Ticket.TicketId, returnUrl = queryString }), "http", Request.Url.Host)
                                    + "'>Go to your ticket</a>";
```

I'm expecting `Request.QueryString["ReturnURL"]` to be equal to the URL I'm opening from the email, so I can redirect to it in my Index method of a controller.

Right now, I'm able to navigate to that URL if I'm already authenticated.
However, if I'm signed off and try to navigate to that URL, Login page is opened first. Then I need to login and should be automatically get redirected to the URL I clicked in my email.

How can I do that?

What am I missing here?

Comment: Sorry, I am confused what's the question? `Right now, I'm able to open that URL only if a user is authenticated already. However, if he is signed off and clicks on that URL, he needs to login first and be redirected to the correct URL.` Sounds like it does what it should be doing? Need to be login before you can access the page...?

Comment: I want the user to be redirected to the URL he clicked on in the email right after he is authenticated. Currently, returnUrl is null after authentication. I also rephrase the question

Comment: Well, is there a `ReturnURL` parameter in the query string if you navigate to the URL without logging in? Note that case matters. You should also make sure your configuration is correct in Web.config.

Comment: @gene How do the user gets to the login page when he tries to open the original URL from the email but isn't authenticated?

Comment: No, there is no `ReturnURL` parameter in the url that is emailed

Comment: If there's no `ReturnUrl` in the URL that is emailed, then what is the point of this `Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]` ?

Comment: Does MVC automatically identifies which URL was redirected from?

Comment: Depends how you set it up/configured your authentication, framework should do that for you from `[Authorize]` attribute... Take a look at your URL when your at login screen, does it have `ReturnUrl` query string?

Comment: No it does not have it. I also, added returnUrl containing my link to the query string and I see it in the email, but login screen does not have it. I also modified the code to show how I create URL for the email